# Why won't program run? Learn Python 3 the Hard Way ex23

Tags: macos, python-3.x

First off, I am a complete beginner with Python and I'm working my way through Zed Shaw's latest edition of Learn Python 3 the Hard Way. Im stuck on ex 23 String, Bytes, and Character Encoding. I can't get the program to run at all in the OSX terminal. When I attempt run the program it just returns zero information.

Here is a link to the screenshot of my terminal after I attempt to run the program.( Apparently i'm too much of a noob to embed my image lol.)

[OSX python3.6 ex23.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgi77.png)

```
import sys
script, input_encoding, error = sys.argv


def main(language_file, encoding, errors):
    line = language_file.readline()

    if line:
        print_line(line, encoding, errors)
        return main(language_file, encoding, errors)


    def print_line(line, encoding, errors):
        next_lang = line.strip()
        raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding, errors=errors)
        cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, error=errors)

        print(raw_bytes, "<===>", cooked_string)


        languages = open("languages.txt", encoding="utf-8")

        main(languages, input_encoding, error)
```

Why is this not running? What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is not just incorrect indentation? Python uses indentation instead of braces to structure its programs. Looking at your code, it seems that you have extra indentations, try this:

```
import sys
script, input_encoding, error = sys.argv

def main(language_file, encoding, errors):
    line = language_file.readline()

    if line:
        print_line(line, encoding, errors)
        return main(language_file, encoding, errors)

def print_line(line, encoding, errors):
    next_lang = line.strip()
    raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding, errors=errors)
    cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, errors=errors)

    print(raw_bytes, "<===>", cooked_string)

languages = open("languages.txt", encoding="utf-8")
main(languages, input_encoding, error)
```

Comment: Dominikas-MacBook-Air:lpthw carmineinteso$ python3.6 ex23.py utf-8 strict
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex23.py", line 23, in <module>
    main(languages, input_encoding, error)
  File "ex23.py", line 9, in main
    print_line(line, encoding, errors)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'print_line' referenced before assignment
Dominikas-MacBook-Air:lpthw carmineinteso$

Comment: Edited the answer. The function `print_line()` did have extra indentation.

Comment: I  copy and pasted the edited code from your answer and ran it in the terminal. It came back with an error message.                                                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex23.py", line 19, in <module>
    main(languages, input_encoding, error)
  File "ex23.py", line 8, in main
    print_line(line, encoding, errors)
  File "ex23.py", line 14, in print_line
    cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, error=errors)
TypeError: 'error' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
Dominikas-MacBook-Air:lpthw carmineinteso$

Comment: You might have missed an `s` there . . . edited again.

Comment: I also want to point out that i wrote it exactly as it was written in the book and that's what led to my original problem. Like i said i'm a beginner with python so i apologize if im causing any unnecessary hair pulling

Comment: That made it run! Thank you!

Comment: If your problem is resolved please accept the answer. Anyways, the error message (almost) always shows you where to look at, so next time you found an error first check it on that specific location. Good luck!